# how can i find the location of the Revit Project Base Point

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We want to show a marker on the different origin locations of Revit files.
I can show the Revit Iternal Point (viewer.model.getData().refPointTransform)
and also the Survey Point (viewer.model.getGlobalOffset())
currently I can not find any reference to the Project Base point

Comment: as far as I know base point from source Revit model is always (0,0,0), In default, Forge Viewer will load the model by aligning the model boundingbox center to the origin of Forge Viewer coordinate. getGlobalOffset tells the offset. So by  reversing calculating, you will get the base point of the source model.

Comment: Survey point should be refPointTransform.

Comment: Now I'm totaly lost. I can not get any reference to the different Revit Origins. See image [here](https://docs.b360.autodesk.com/shares/c329d3c7-637c-4091-8e5a-c8b8a9f39a69) and  the small Revit file [here](https://docs.b360.autodesk.com/shares/b23781bc-b6aa-4f26-b1fe-317020a6f60e) GetGlobalOffset and refPointtransform give me vector(0,0,0) wich in the example Revit file is the Revit internal point

Comment: I will investigate your model and get back to you as soon as possible. currently, I am busy on an event. Will try best to get back to you in the two days. thank you for patience

Comment: I investigated your model and checked every possible value. Also checked setting of Revit, but did not seem to find why the values are (0,0,0). Please bear with me checking with engineer team.

Comment: Any update from engineering on this?

Comment: sorry for my late response! What I got is model.getData().metadata has the values you are looking for: positionLL84 and refPointLMV. Project base point coordinates (positionLL84) are in the form of [longitude (in degrees), latitude (in degrees), elevation (in feet)], and thus (sometimes) would be "invalid" (when the longitude and latitude cannot be determined with the coordinate system)
Survey point coordinates (refPointLMV) are in Revit internal model space with unit feet

Comment: I was further checking about the relationship with refPointTransform. and forgot to reply you with the update above. my apology again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the global offset is not the position of the project base point since the project base point is movable in Revit by changing its `'E/W'`, `N/S`, and `Elev` parameters.

Now I figured it out. We can get the project base point's position in Revit internal coordinate system by the following:

```js
async getProjectLocationToModelTransformation(model) {
    const aecModelData = await Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getAecModelData(model.getDocumentNode());
    const refPointTransformation = this.readMatrixFromArray12(aecModelData.refPointTransformation);

    const projectLocationToModelTransformation = new SylvesterMatrix(refPointTransformation.elements).inverse().toThreeMatrix4();
    return projectLocationToModelTransformation;
}

async getBasePointData(model, category = 'Revit Base Point') {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const found = await this.searchAsync(model, category, ['Category'], { searchHidden: true });
        if (!found || found.length <= 0) return reject('Base point not found');

        const result = await this.getBulkProperties2Async(found, { propFilter: ['N/S', 'E/W', 'Elev', 'Angle to True North'] }, model);

        if (!result) return reject('Base point not found');

        const data = result[0];
        return resolve(data);
    });
}

async reportProjectBasePoint(model, useViewerSpace = false) {
    const projectLocationToModelTransformation = await this.getProjectLocationToModelTransformation(model);
    const basePointData = await this.getBasePointData(model);

    const eastWestProp = basePointData.properties.find(p => p.attributeName == 'E/W');
    const northSouthProp = basePointData.properties.find(p => p.attributeName == 'N/S');
    const elevProp = basePointData.properties.find(p => p.attributeName == 'Elev');
    const angletonProp = basePointData.properties.find(p => p.attributeName == 'Angle to True North');

    const eastWestVal = Autodesk.Viewing.Private.convertToDisplayUnits(eastWestProp.displayValue, eastWestProp.type, eastWestProp.units, model.getUnitString());
    const northSouthVal = Autodesk.Viewing.Private.convertToDisplayUnits(northSouthProp.displayValue, northSouthProp.type, northSouthProp.units, model.getUnitString());
    const elevVal = Autodesk.Viewing.Private.convertToDisplayUnits(elevProp.displayValue, elevProp.type, elevProp.units, model.getUnitString());

    const basePoint = new THREE.Vector3(eastWestVal.displayValue, northSouthVal.displayValue, elevVal.displayValue);
    const basePointInRvt = basePoint.clone().applyMatrix4(projectLocationToModelTransformation);
    if (useViewerSpace)
        return basePointInRvt.clone().applyMatrix4(model.getModelToViewerTransform());

    return basePointInRvt;
}

await reportProjectBasePoint(viewer.getAllModels()[0]); //!<<< PBP position in Revit space
await reportProjectBasePoint(viewer.getAllModels()[0], true); //!<<< PBP position in viewer space
```

Please find here for the full code:
https://gist.github.com/yiskang/e96f544252a989daef022cd89e799f46

Here is my test result:
[image]